# I want to know the volume of the enclosed space 0<xy<z<1

Tags: calculus, integration

Here, $x,y$ and $z$ are real numbers and they are satisfied with these all conditions.

$0 \leqq x \leqq 1$

$0 \leqq y \leqq 1$

$0 \leqq z \leqq 1$

$0 \leqq xy \leqq z \leqq 1$

And I would like to know the volume of the space which $x,y$ and $z$ satisfied with these conditions in $\mathbb{R}^3$

In this case, should I calculate below integral?

$$ \int_0^1 dz \int_0^{z/x} dy \int_0^{z/y} dz$$

Comment: The volume should be 
$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int _{xy}^1 dzdydx=\int_0^1\int_^1 (1-xy)dydx$.

Comment: @student I think you meant $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int _{xy}^1 dzdydx=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (1-xy)dydx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integration limits don't make sense, even after correcting the last $\mathrm{d}z$ to $\mathrm{d}x$.  Just read it from left to right.  First we have $0\leq z\leq1$.  That's fine.  Then we have $0\leq y\leq {z\over x}$, but $x$ hasn't been defined yet, so this can't be right.

The way to do it is shown in the comments.  $x$ and $y$ can take any values in $[0,1]$ and $z$ must be $\geq$ their product.

Comment: Thank you. So, is the answer 3/4?